# Is there any distance function such that $g(\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c}) = g(\mathbf{b}) + g(\mathbf{c})$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Suppose that we have
$$\mathbf{a}_i - \mathbf{a}_j = \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{c},$$
where all variables are of the same dimension (i.e., $n$ dimensional). If we let $g(\mathbf{a}_i-\mathbf{a}_j)$ denote the squared Euclidean distance between $\mathbf{a}_i$ and $\mathbf{a}_j$, then the following is not true
$$g(\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c})  = g(\mathbf{b}) + g(\mathbf{c})\;$$
because $g(\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c})=(b_1+c_1)^2+...+(b_n+c_n)^2 \ne b_1^2+c_1^2+...+b_n^2+c_n^2=g(\mathbf{b}) + g(\mathbf{c}).$

Is there any distance function $g(\cdot)$ such that
$$g(\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c}) = g(\mathbf{b}) + g(\mathbf{c})\;?$$

Comment: What are you defining as distance function? Metrics induced by norms? Norms themselves?

Comment: It's a little odd call $\|\cdot\|$ a "distance" function. A distance function (usually called a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space)) is a function of **two** arguments (the two objects you are measuring how far they are).

Comment: The question in the header doesn't match the one in the body (and neither question is clear).

Comment: @gist076923 I updated the question's notation.

Comment: @jjagmath I updated the question's notation.

Comment: @lulu Is it more clear now?

Comment: A trivial $g$ is $g(\mathbf v) = 0$ for all $\mathbf v$.

Comment: No, not really.  As others have remarked, a "distance function" needs two arguments, not $1$.  Maybe you are talking about a norm, but that's not clear either.  I suggest:  rather than using words loosely, why not just list the properties you want your function to have?

Comment: @lulu I suppose g() is inspired by the squared Euclidean distance function, but it is not a distance function itself.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by a "distance function". If you mean a norm (or some function of a norm like the squared euclidean distance), then this is trivially doesn't exist because homogeneity scuppers things via $g(0) = g(x) + g(- x) = 2g(x)$. To be more formal, look at, e.g., the properties in the standard definitions of a norm (or metric). Which of these do you want to retain?

Comment: "inspired by" is not precise.  Just list the exact properties you have in mind.

Comment: @lulu I think the answers cover the issue. Thanks for commenting, though!

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Based on your comment and the answers, it looks like what I want is not going to be possible. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: When you rewrote the $\|\cdot\|$ as $g(\cdot)$, do you still want to preserve that $g(\cdot) \ge 0$, like other "distance functions" or norms?

Comment: Again, you should stop calling "distance" a function of only one argument. "The distance of Chicago" makes no sense. "The distance **between** Chicago and New York" makes sense. See? You need to talk about the distance between **two** things. You could call the function the "size" of the vector or the "norm" of the vector.

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, that would be preferable! :)

Comment: @jjagmath Great point. The function of g should be something like "size" rather than distance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering a *normed* space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ and $X$ consists of more than $0$, then $\|x+y\| = \|x\| + \|y\|$ cannot hold for every $x,y$. Take for example $x\neq y$ and $y = -x$, then you get $0 = \|x-x\| = \|x\| + \|x\|$, which implies $\|x\| = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = 0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if $X$ is any set with at least $2$ elements then you can't define any metric on it such that the triangle inequality is always an equality. Indeed, if $x\ne y$ then $d(x,x)=0$ is strictly smaller than $d(x,y)+d(y,x)=2d(x,y)$.

In particular, a norm like you want exists only for a trivial vector space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!